# Importing external table using multiple conditions sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I would like import some selected rows  from an external table into HDFS directory using sqoop
Below is table rows in MYSQL database
The column names are name,bank,salary,company

```
Surender,HDFC,60000,CTS
Raja,AXIS,80000,TCS
Raj,HDFC,70000,TCS
Kumar,AXIS,70000,CTS
```

all I need is to have multiple where conditions in sqoop commands. How to  have multiple where conditions in sqoop commands.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.891.289.1/testing --username root -P 
--query 'select * from records where salary>30000 and bank='HDFC' $CONDITIONS'
--target-dir '/user/cloudera/surender' -m 1
```

The above query is returning error. I am getting error as "Unknown column "HDFC" in where clause

Comment: I tried with bank="HDFC" in where condition..it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you need to put "and" before `$CONDITIONS`. Instead of:

```
where salary>30000 and bank='HDFC' $CONDITIONS
```

Try using

```
where salary>30000 and bank='HDFC' and \$CONDITIONS'
```